After resetting the ag-grid height, the agSelectCellEditor displays abnormally
I'm using ag-grid on my webpage with the official agSelectCellEditor for managing a list of colors. Above the ag-grid, there's a component (highlighted in a red box in the diagram) that allows modifying the ag-grid height.

When I load the webpage without adjusting the ag-grid height manually, the dropdown menu works fine.

However, after adjusting the ag-grid height, the display becomes problematic. The ag-grid content gets squeezed out of its containing div, seemingly due to the select list pushing it off-screen. I'm unsure how to resolve this issue. What should I do to fix it?


After my investigation last night, I found that adding the corresponding CSS in the file ensures that the popup will display in the correct position.
:host ::ng-deep .ag-popup{ position: absolute;}

